# shell script cut and sed help

Tags: linux, shell

I have 2 two files

```
$cat file1.txt
 field1=value1
 field2=value2
 field3=value3
 ::
 ::

 $cat file2.txt
 something.field1.some
 otherthing.field2.anything
 anything.field3.something
```

I need to read file1.txt and check whether file2.txt for fieldN and replace with valueN

so that the result will be

```
  something.value1.some
  otherthing.value2.anything
  anything.value3.something
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided there are no special `sed`-type characters in your fields and values, you can use a `meta-sed` approach:

```
pax> sed -e 's/^/s\/\\./' -e 's/=/\\.\/./' -e 's/$/.\/g/' file1.txt >x.sed
pax> sed -f x.sed file2.txt

something.value1.some
otherthing.value2.anything
anything.value3.something
```

If you look at the `x.sed` file, you'll see that the first `sed` just makes a list of `sed` commands to be executed on your second file.

Answer (score 2):

use awk

```
$ awk -F"[=.]" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2=a[$2]}1' OFS="." file1 file2
something.value1.some
otherthing.value2.anything
anything.value3.something
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,I'll use this method after learning about awk.  i know something about sed but zero at awk :) thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately requires the files to be sorted:

```
tr = . < file1.txt | join -t . -1 1 -2 2 -o 2.1 1.2 2.3 - file2.txt
```